# Calculate Mann-Kendall by iterating through multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas

I need to calculate Mann-Kendall for precipitation values across each county in my dataset. There are 991 rows for each county. Is there a way to create a loop that takes each county name (could be a string or integer) and calculates the Mann-Kendall saving the result to a new dataframe/excel file?

So for example, my dataframe looks something like this:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'County': ['Adair', 'Adair', 'Adair', 'Allegany', 'Allegany', 'Allegany', 'Alexander', 'Alexander', 'Alexander'], 'Value': [1, 2, 4, 1, 2, -1, 0, 2, 1]})
```

My ideal output would look like:

```
Adair: Mann-Kendall Result    
Allegany: Mann-Kendall Result    
Alexander: Mann-Kendall Result
```

The code I have so far is embarrassingly simple, but hasn't worked the way I want it to:

```
result = pd.DataFrame()
for index in data:
    mann = mk.original_test(test1[index])
    result.append(mann)
```

Comment: does this works: `df_mk=data.groupby('County')['Value'].agg(mk.original_test)`?

Comment: Yes I believe so! Now I feel really silly for not thinking of that myself

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate mk for each County using `group by`:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'County': ['Adair', 'Adair', 'Adair', 'Allegany', 'Allegany', 'Allegany', 'Alexander', 'Alexander', 'Alexander'],
                     'Value': [1, 2, 4, 1, 2, -1, 0, 2, 1]})    
df_mk=data.groupby('County')['Value'].agg(mk.original_test).reset_index()
```

You 'll get a named tuple in "Value" column and to get each parameter into separate column you can do the following:

```
param_cols='trend h p z Tau s var_s slope intercept'.split()
df_mk[param_cols]=[row for row in df_mk['Value']]
```